# how to set admin.site.urls as home page in django

Tags: django

some question about django 1.10:

I am going to make a website and the home page should be a login page created by django,when i tried to make the admin login page as my site's home page,it failed,can anybody help me ?

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$', include(admin.site.urls)), ]
```

or

```
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$', admin.site.urls), ]
```

both works wrong.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, setting **admin page** as the **main page** is not a good idea but still, whatever the use case is, try this:

`url(r'^', admin.site.urls),`

Tested it on Django 1.9 but I think it'll work on Django 1.10 as well.
**Also**, don't forget to restart the server after making these changes.

Answer (score 3):

**For djanog version 2 & later**, the syntax `url()` has been replaced & *simplified* with `path()`
So, **if you have django version >=2** , use this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/) for details.